# Rails 3 local variable is not being passed to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, partial, local-variables

has anyone an idea why I have the following problem with passing locals to a Ruby partial ?

My partial (excerpt):

```
 <div class="control-group">
   <%= field_prefix %>
   <%= label_tag t("shared.email"),nil,:class => "control-label" %>
   <div class="controls">
   <%= email_field_tag "[email]", contact.nil? ? "" : contact[:email]  %>
   </div>
 </div>
```

My partial is included in the following way:

```
 <%= render "shared/contact", :field_prefix => 123 , :contact => @person.contact %>
```

Also if i do it this way it wont`t work, the second local i pass (field_prefix) is not passed:

```
 <%= render :partial => "shared/contact", :locals => {:field_prefix => 123 , :contact => @person.contact } %>
```

I always get the error message that the local variable "field_prefix" is not recognized:

> undefined local variable or method `field_prefix' for #<#:0x5837418>

It`s coming from the partial view.

Comment: Does it help to change `field_prefix` to symbol `:field_prefix` on the second line of the partial ?

Comment: seems to be a cache or IDE problem (bug?) see my last post, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most of the time I really like Ruby but sometimes it is very very annoying and mysterious :-/

I had to restart my IDE (RubyMine) and the integrated server to get it working without chaning any source.

Of course the sources were saved also yesterday when I tried it first but there seems to be a cache or something like that in this IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Just a sanity check, are you sure the partial you are looking at is the right one? When this has happened to me I thought I was looking at the right file and ended up realizing that I was looking at the wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, restarting RubyMine was not enough but going through a couple of steps of File > Repair IDE did the trick