# Partial variables availiable only through local_assigns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to pass parameters to a partial view from another partial view

**_discussion.html.erb**

```
<%= render :partial => 'text_posts/show', :locals =>{:post => post.specific, :receiver => receiver} %>
```

**text_posts\_show.html.erb**

```
<div class="name"><a><%= post.user.first_name %></a></div>
```

when i debug the _show file, i can see that both "post" and "receiver" are nil, while local_assigns[:posts] and local_assign[:receiver] contain my objects.

I can access my params through local_assigns but it feels wrong.. any ideas why this happens? Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: can you try with parenthesis? `<%= render(:partial => 'text_posts/show', :locals =>{:post => post.specific, :receiver => receiver}) %>` Because your code is supposed to work

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I've tried the parenthesis and i get the same result

Comment: Can you try without the `:locals =>`? like this: `<%= render :partial => 'text_posts/show', {:post => post.specific, :receiver => receiver} %>`

Comment: i get "Expected: =>" error. I'm using rails 3.2.13.

Comment: What about this? : `<%= render({:partial => 'text_posts/show'}, {:post => post.specific, :receiver => receiver}) %>`

Comment: OH, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106883/rails-3-local-variable-is-not-being-passed-to-partial

Comment: didn't work. This makes the local_assigns empty

Comment: Walla!! I will try this now

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :|

Comment: Wow, that's weird! Try to restart the server + browser + empty the cache + restart your IDE. Because I am right now using the syntax `render :partial => 'a/path/to/partial', locals: { dummy: data }` so it should work for you!

Comment: How are you passing the variables in your _discussion.html.erb partial?

Comment: Eventually i cleared RubyMine's cache, restarted the server and it solved the problem. Mr Yoshiji - you are awesome!